# Google Drive API throws numerous 500 errors since 4/29/2014

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

We use the Google Drive API to integrate spreadsheets with our app and it appears since 4/29 our drive account has changed and we are getting many 500 errors with POSTs/PUTs/GETs throughout the day. These would happen very infrequently before.

We are running on Ruby and are using the following library to access Google.

https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby

An example is error is below:

Response code 500 for post https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1CPREPYM4D9JYuh_ZWivFxBvywgGpjdmWi9S95Jz4YyE/oq33sul/private/full/batch: Google Drive Error/* Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. */
.goog-inline-block{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block}* html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}*:first-child+html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}#drive-logo{color:#91959c;font-family:"Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif;font-size:27px;font-weight:300;position:absolute;text-shadow:0 1px 1px white;white-space:nowrap}#drive-logo img{padding:0 0.4em 0 0;position:relative;top:2px;vertical-align:middle}#drive-logo a{color:#91959c;text-decoration:none}#drive-logo span.goog-inline-block{margin-top:2px;vertical-align:top}body {background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}a, a:link, a:visited {color: #112ABB;}.errorMessage {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%;}DriveGoogle Drive encountered an error. If reloading the page doesn't help, please report the error.

To learn more about Google Drive, please visit our help center.

**We're sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks for your help!**
*- The Google Drive Team*

Thanks

Yilmaz

Comment: 500 indicates an error on their side.  You would be better served getting in touch with them about what's going on with their API as opposed to us.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you need to contact Google.

Comment: I am experiencing this as well.

Comment: Same issue?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199031/google-docs-sheets-api-ongoing-outage-influx-of-500-errors