# Google Docs/Sheets API Ongoing Outage - Influx of 500 Errors

Tags: google-api

We're experiencing hundreds of thousands of 500 status code responses across the past couple days:

```
We&#39;re sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet.
```

Here is a raw request: https://gist.github.com/bryanhelmig/3dba25ec63e82221855b

- They are almost entirely on GET https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full
- This started happening across the past 5-7 days
- It happens across many user accounts - it is not tied to a specific user
- Approximately ~8% for those API calls are 5xx, the others are a mix of 200/304/etc. as expected

Happy to provide more, deeper raw logs to anyone listening at Google. bryan@zapier.com is the best contact for me.

Comment: It is also now happening in communities and the google+ framework.

Comment: I am experiencing this as well.

Answer (score 2):

From your description it doesn't sound like anything you are doing. If you file an issue on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list) we can dig into more detail.